# createBlobURL()

Tags: html

Is it true that if use createBlobURL(), file data is not loaded into memory? So is it alright to use it for images and video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the [WebKit source](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=de#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/fileapi/BlobURL.cpp&q=createbloburl&d=5&l=73) I would say the function only creates an URL in the following form:

```
blob:<encoded original url>/<uuid>
```

There doesn't seem to appear any loading of the URL's source.

Answer (score 0):

The file contents are not loaded into JS memory, but the browser does create a handle to the file. So, calling createObjectURL() doesn't come for free. Chrome has a nice chrome://blob-internals/ page to see all the Blob URLs created.

Just remember to call revokeObjectURL() when you're done.